# Running the Tensorflow 2.0 code gives 'ValueError: tf.function-decorated function tried to create variables on non-first call'. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, keras-layer, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

[error_giving_notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1lipWy-B6BrtZlARM_amdnc7zgKiFaSRR)

[non_problematic_notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ksJgAXniJZIm8S4EmPDIE3hA7DuwWs0a)

As it can be seen that I have used tf.function decorator in the 'error_giving_notebook' and it throws a ValueError while the same notebook without any changes except for removing the tf.function decorator runs smoothly in 'non_problematic_notebook'. What can be the reason?

Comment: If seems you're calling the functions more than once and the functions are trying to create new variables while they should only create new variables in the first call? --- By tje way, I never used `@tf.function` for training loops, is there a special reason you want to use it?

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/performance#variables --- I'm not sure what is creating a new var in your code inside these functions, but maybe the gradient tape is doing that....

Comment: Thinking better about it, I believe that a graph version of the training should use `tf.gradients` instead of gradient tape. But for `tf.gradients` to work, the entire model from start to end must be a graph too. (Which seems ok in your case). Now, if your code is only what is in the notebook, you might really consider just using `model.fit()` with a callback instead of a custom training loop.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem here is in the return values of the call method of class conv2d:

```
if self.bias:
  if self.pad == 'REFLECT':
    self.p = (self.filter_size - 1) // 2
    self.x = tf.pad(inputs, [[0, 0], [self.p, self.p], [self.p, self.p], [0, 0]], 'REFLECT')
    return Conv2D(filters=self.filter_num, kernel_size=(self.filter_size, self.filter_size), strides=(self.stride, self.stride),
                                  padding='VALID', use_bias=True, kernel_initializer=self.w, bias_initializer=self.b)(self.x)
  else:
    return Conv2D(filters=self.filter_num, kernel_size=(self.filter_size, self.filter_size), strides=(self.stride, self.stride),
                                  padding=self.pad, use_bias=True, kernel_initializer=self.w, bias_initializer=self.b)(inputs)
else:
   if self.pad == 'REFLECT':
      self.p = (self.filter_size - 1) // 2
      self.x = tf.pad(inputs, [[0, 0], [self.p, self.p], [self.p, self.p], [0, 0]], 'REFLECT')
      return Conv2D(filters=self.filter_num, kernel_size=(self.filter_size, self.filter_size), strides=(self.stride, self.stride),
                                  padding='VALID', use_bias=False, kernel_initializer=self.w)(self.x)
   else:
      return Conv2D(filters=self.filter_num, kernel_size=(self.filter_size, self.filter_size), strides=(self.stride, self.stride),
                                  padding=self.pad, use_bias=False, kernel_initializer=self.w)(inputs)
```

By returning a Conv2D object tf.Variable(s) are created (weights, bias of conv layer) each time you call

```
predictions = model(images)
```

in your tf-decorated function. Hence, the exception.

One possible way to solve this problem is by changing the build and call method in your conv2d class as follow:

```
def build(self, inputs):
  self.w = tf.random_normal_initializer(mean=0.0, stddev=1e-4)
  if self.bias:
    self.b = tf.constant_initializer(0.0)
  else:
    self.b = None

  self.conv_a = Conv2D(filters=self.filter_num, kernel_size=(self.filter_size, self.filter_size), strides=(self.stride, self.stride), padding='VALID', use_bias=True, kernel_initializer=self.w, bias_initializer=self.b)
  self.conv_b = Conv2D(filters=self.filter_num, kernel_size=(self.filter_size, self.filter_size), strides=(self.stride, self.stride), padding=self.pad, use_bias=True, kernel_initializer=self.w, bias_initializer=self.b)
  self.conv_c = Conv2D(filters=self.filter_num, kernel_size=(self.filter_size, self.filter_size), strides=(self.stride, self.stride), padding='VALID', use_bias=False, kernel_initializer=self.w)
  self.conv_d = Conv2D(filters=self.filter_num, kernel_size=(self.filter_size, self.filter_size), strides=(self.stride, self.stride),padding=self.pad, use_bias=False, kernel_initializer=self.w)  

def call(self, inputs):
  if self.bias:
    if self.pad == 'REFLECT':
      self.p = (self.filter_size - 1) // 2
      self.x = tf.pad(inputs, [[0, 0], [self.p, self.p], [self.p, self.p], [0, 0]], 'REFLECT')
      return self.conv_a(self.x)
    else:
      return self.conv_b(inputs)
  else:
     if self.pad == 'REFLECT':
        self.p = (self.filter_size - 1) // 2
        self.x = tf.pad(inputs, [[0, 0], [self.p, self.p], [self.p, self.p], [0, 0]], 'REFLECT')
        return self.conv_c(self.x)
     else:
        return self.conv_d(inputs)
```

To better understand AutoGraph and how @tf.function works I suggest taking a look at [this](https://pgaleone.eu/tensorflow/tf.function/2019/03/21/dissecting-tf-function-part-1/)

Answer (score 101):

As you are trying to use function decorator in TF 2.0, please enable run function eagerly by using below line after importing TensorFlow:

```
tf.config.experimental_run_functions_eagerly(True)
```

Since the above is deprecated(no longer experimental?), please use the following instead:

```
tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)
```

If you want to know more do refer to [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/run_functions_eagerly) link.

Comment: I was actually using a shared layer that was causing the error. This saved me from madness thank you!

Comment: This error can happen when using Keras. In order to use this solution just do `import tensorflow as tf` then do `tf.config...`

Comment: Take a look at this : [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27120)

Comment: so the solution is loosing 90% of performance of TF?

Answer (score 3):

Please use the following line after importing TensorFlow to enable run function eagerly as you attempt to utilize the function decorator in TF 2.0:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone getting this error in Google Colab:

I was getting the same error while following the [TensorFlow 2 quickstart for beginners tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/quickstart/beginner) using Google Colab.

What probably happened with me is that I ran a few cells twice and started getting this error at one point. I just ran everything from the first cell in one go from `Runtime > Run after` (while I was at the first cell in colab) and it worked.

Comment: Run All works for me